# What kind of Data object would I use for a bulk data import in C# web.api?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have the following set of data that needs to be sent to my api and I not sure what data type to use:

```
{"UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData": [
  {
   "Name": "test",
   "Active": true,
   "UnitOfMeasureTypeID": "dd89f0a0-59c3-49a1-a2ae-7e763da32065",
   "BaseUnitID": "4da30098-3574-4a0c-a07f-c185ef34defe",
   "BaseUnitName": null,
   "BaseUnitAbbreviation": null,
   "RelatedUnitDisplayOrder": 1,
   "RelatedUnitName": "Foot",
   "RelatedUnitAbbreviation": "ft",
   "RelatedUnitConversionRatio": 12,
   "UnitOfMeasureSetID": "12a7c55a-6dcd-7261-c9e3-f1010bf836de"
  },
  {
    ...
  }
 ]
}
```

My api method:

```
[Route("api/admin/UnitsOfMeasure/UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitsCreate")]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(UnitsOfMeasure.UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage))]
public IHttpActionResult UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitsCreate(UnitsOfMeasure.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound)
{
    UnitsOfMeasure _oUnitsOfMeasure = new UnitsOfMeasure();
    return Ok(_oUnitsOfMeasure.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnits_Create(UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound));
}
```

My data class:

```
public class UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Guid> UnitOfMeasureTypeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Guid> BaseUnitID { get; set; }
    public string BaseUnitName { get; set; }
    public string BaseUnitAbbreviation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RelatedUnitDisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public string RelatedUnitName { get; set; }
    public string RelatedUnitAbbreviation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> RelatedUnitConversionRatio { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Guid> UnitOfMeasureSetID { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have tried `List<...>` and no list and the only thing that is being passed in is null data.

So what data type do I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need:

```
var UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData = new List<UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound>()
```

You might also need to show us the implementation of Ok() so we can see how you are serializing the data.

Here is a some code to show you what I mean https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ty4WrI

Comment: Right now the Ok() only returns an empty set, more concerned with passing in the data first.

Comment: Well after instantiating UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData you then call UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData.Add() to add your UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound's. Perhaps if you show us the code for UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnits_Create() and UnitsOfMeasure we can see what you are doing internally.

Comment: I tied the `List<>` type and i still get a null inbound where as I need to be able to get anywhere from 1 record to n number of records.

Comment: Can you show me the code I asked for above? You are not creating an instance of UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound when you pass it in, so unless you are dynamically instantiating that type it stands to reason you are seeing a null.

Comment: as mentioned the only thing I have in that part of the code is to return a null object `public UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnits_Create(UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound _UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound){ UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage _oUnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage = new UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage(); return _oUnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage;}` What is important at this moment is to be able to send from my front end a json array object that contains multiple records of that data type above and have it parsed as a list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81228/discussion-between-theedge-and-john-schultz).

Comment: I think I found an answer but before I post it, I need to know how to replace all occurrences of \" in my JSON string to a single ". I have tried `.Replace("\"", """")` and `.Replace("\"", (char)34)` - after converting the (char)34 to a string and I still get \".

Comment: Disregard the conversion, I am able to get the array in, unfortunately ATM, its only taking the first set, not all four. My code to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the name of the parameter in the API Method and the JSON array are same. For example, if your method signature is
    public IHttpActionResult UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitsCreate(UnitsOfMeasure.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound _unitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound) { ... }

then the Json object should be,
    {"_unitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound": [
    {
    "Name": "test",
    "Active": true,
    "UnitOfMeasureTypeID": "dd89f0a0-59c3-49a1-a2ae-7e763da32065",
    "BaseUnitID": "4da30098-3574-4a0c-a07f-c185ef34defe",
    "BaseUnitName": null,
    "BaseUnitAbbreviation": null,
    "RelatedUnitDisplayOrder": 1,
    "RelatedUnitName": "Foot",
    "RelatedUnitAbbreviation": "ft",
    "RelatedUnitConversionRatio": 12,
    "UnitOfMeasureSetID": "12a7c55a-6dcd-7261-c9e3-f1010bf836de"
    },
    {
    ...
    }
    ]
    }

Answer (score 0):

API Call:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

[Route("api/admin/UnitsOfMeasure/UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitsCreate")]
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(UnitsOfMeasure.UnitsOfMeasureDataWithMessage))]
public IHttpActionResult UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitsCreate([FromBody] JObject UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound)
{
    var json = "[" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound) + "]";
    List<UnitsOfMeasure.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound> plist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UnitsOfMeasure.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound>>(json);
    return Ok();
}
```

This only returns the first record, however it might be a step in the right direction.

**EDIT**

Used the following Code:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound);
var jo = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var _UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData = jo["UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound"];
var _UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UnitsOfMeasure.UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitDataInbound>>(_UnitOfMeasureRelatedUnitData.ToString());
```

and now I get all my elements.

Comment: Nope, this actually does return all elements, there is something wrong with my original json.